# CodingBat xyzThere

Tags: java

> Return true if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not.

I am trying this problem out and cant seem to find why "abc.xyzxyz" is still returning false

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
   if(str.contains("xyz")) {
      int xyz = str.indexOf("xyz");
      if(xyz!=0 && str.substring(xyz-1,xyz).equals(".")) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;  
}
```

Comment: Good code formatting helps both you and us. Please do improve your posted code's formatting to allow all of us to better see what is going on.

Comment: I thought this was formatted just fine

Comment: Shoot I'll do it myself, but next time, please put in the effort to try to make it easier for all to understand. Re, `"I thought this was formatted just fine"` -- hardly, you had several code blocks all on the same level of indentation, and some blocks not indented at all. Please read up on this subject since understanding code formatting will only help you (and us) in the future.

Comment: Ah i see now, thank you. Do you see why this code would return "abc.xyzxyz" as false?

Answer (score 1):

It returns false because this statement, `if(xyz!=0 && str.substring(xyz-1,xyz).equals(".")) {` is true.

xyz is 4, and `str.substring(3, 4)` is "."

Comment: Ah now i see where the problem lies , what would you suggest i do so that it will return true. the .xyzxyz gets past the str.contain and gets caught at second if statement. every other input works except when the string contains both .xyz and xyz seperately

Comment: @Tolkingdom: your method could do it in one line of code, with two boolean tests combined with an `&&` operator, that's it. But you should experiment and try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: i have tried if(str.contains("xyz")&&!str.contains(".xyz") if that is what your referring to , it gets caught in the exact same spot

Comment: @Tolkingdom: yep, that's exactly it! Please edit your original question, don't delete the current code as that will invalidate my answer, but add your new attempt as an edit below it. Let's take a look at it.